# Number of parallel/ duplicate edges in a Graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am creating a Graph (can't use Multigraph) by iterating over a df. Some rows in the df are exactly the same. So, the edge won't be repeated in the graph. But, I'd like to have an attribute added to each edge with following possible values.

`0` : edge does not have a duplicate in the df

`1`: edge has a duplicate in the df

For example, I have a df like this
[image: df]

I'd like the edges `(1,2), (1,3)` to have an attribute `duplicate=1`and the edge `(2,5)` to have `duplicate=0`.

Comment: What have you tried and what does your dataframe look like? Your code would be good to include here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing how you have coded this, in pseudo code you could do something like the following:

```
for row in df:
    if (row.from, row.to) in graph:
        graph[(row.from, row.to)].duplicate +=1
    else:
        graph.append[(row.from,row.to)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `G.number_of_edges(1,2)` to get the number of edges between `1` and `2` in a multigraph `G`.  Here is [the documentation.](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.number_of_edges.html)